# Publish Windows App to be Emailed

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, installation, publish, wizard

I have a finished version of an app (made using WPF).  I want to publish it so that the installation files can be emailed to another person.  The only options shown with the Visual Studio 2013 Publish Wizard are "From a Web site", "From a UNC path or file share", or "From a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM".

How can I publish the app so that it goes into a nice and tidy folder on my Desktop which I can simply zip up and email it to someone?  To which they can simply unzip, click setup, and follow the traditional setup wizard.  It needs to be able to run on Windows XP thru Windows 8.

(I have .csv files and image files that the application uses, if it is relevant.)

Comment: you can't email an application. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: You know when you download a program from the internet?  Then you click setup, and the install wizard runs?  I want to get that file so I can email it to someone.

Comment: sorry, maybe I didn't express myself properly. **You can't email an application.**

Comment: Interesting.  Never knew.  Any ideas on how to get it through those little wires without having a website?

Comment: use an FTP, or upload it to dropbox or something like that.

Comment: What HighCore is trying to say is that most email services will not transmit application (.exe files and such), due to being filtered as possible threats (viruses).  Plus... there's the whole size thing, depending on what you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Visual Studio`, highlight the project you want to deploy and right click.  This will raise a context menu which has a '`Publish`' item on it...

[image]

Selecting this will raise a `Wizard` like this...

[image]

From here, select 'Finish'.  This will create a directory with a `Setup.exe` and all the necessary files to install the application on a different machine (given security levels permit, third party software restrictions, and a host of other deployment issues).  You can then create a `zip` file (keeping the directory structure) and email it.

The '`Publish`' feature has other options on it you will want to explore, like `Click Once`.

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty straight forward if you are going to perform zip and email to your subscribers

- begin with publishing the app from `Build -> Publish`
- Choose a path from your local hard drive eg. `C:\Myapp`
- then in next screen choose `From a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM`
- then in next screen choose `The application will not check updates` unless you have a web location where you can publish the updates (which I guess you dont want for now)
- then Finish

and your chosen folder `C:\Myapp` will contain the setup files which `you can zip and email` to your users.