# ClickOnce deployment horrors

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, mage

I am having trouble signing an application after ClickOnce deployment.

The application is a winforms project with 3 class-library projects and is deployed to a shared file path.

Publish from Visual Studio works and if I run the application it installs fine despite the warning in Windows 10 about it being unrecognized:
[image: Windows protected your PC screenshot]

So being a foolishly helpful programmer I thought I'd try to remove the warning message for my users.

- First step was to create a signing certificate. Luckily the sys admin was able to do whip up an internal certificate for me, and I managed to work out how to export it reading [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2014/06/10/how-to-create-and-use-a-code-signing-certificate-for-clickonce-vsto-applications-using-active-directory-certificate-services/).
- Then I used [Mage UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mageui-exe-manifest-generation-and-editing-tool-graphical-client) to sign the manifest. What a "manifest" was exactly I did not know at this stage. Where to find Mage was also an issue as the Windows SDK were not installed on the deployment server. I eventually remoted into the deployment server and ran Mage from my own PC. Using Mage to sign random files I eventually worked out that I needed to sign ALL the .application + .manifest files mentioned in the file structure of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24510906/345659).
- At this point I was stuck with a `Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly` error and after exhausting the 10 different things to try mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5337458/345659) I started posting here.
- Then I found [this MSDN article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bfd7bd12-790b-414d-9f56-d2d8beb0850b/reference-in-the-deployment-does-not-match-the-identity-defined-in-the-application-manifest?forum=winformssetup) where they suggested that the file was in some way corrupt. Which file? Well after comparing the files before and after I noticed that the .application file still had product key = "000000000000000" for the .manifest file instead of the new signed product key.
- So I went back into Mage and reselected the "Application Reference" for the manifest and signed it again. At which point I got another error `could not find a part of the path \\MyFileShare\Application%20Files\MyApplication_1_0_0_23\MyApplication.exe.manifest`
- Eventually I worked out that Mage had delightfully corrupted the file path with urlencoding. I fixed `%20` in notepad to   and resigned in Mage AGAIN and it worked!!!

Surely I'm doing something wrong and Microsoft didn't intend for this to be so difficult?

---

## TLDR;

What is the correct way to run Mage to sign the application in 1 hit, without having to edit the files manually and resign multiple times?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is in the same place in 2015, but in the Project Properties of 2010 there is a Signing tab a couple slots above the Publish tab. For my project that is ClickOnce it has a check box to "Sign the ClickOnce manifests"

Comment: @Lithium Yes I have that option - but I don't have access to the certificate in the development environment, so I need to sign after deployment

Comment: I don't know how "you can't have access to the certificate" in the development environment ? You manage this certificate and deliver it to the production environnement (with your application) and it's the job of the admin to add your certificate in the trusted developper store.

Comment: @MarcoGuignard It is an internal certificate and it is in a separate Active Directory domain (external for me), I can VPN to the production environment as a different user to deploy

Comment: And ? The certificate used to sign an application has nothing to do with an active directory user ! I'm sure that Adobe don't have an user in your production environment. It juste have to be added in the good store to be trusted by the production domain.

Comment: If ClickOnce gets ruled out, Microsoft provide a MSI type installer project for Visual Studio. There is also Squirrel, a self updater that is also used by VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marco Guignard pointed out in the comments it is possible to export a certificate created from **anywhere** and import it into your personal store to use in Visual Studio.

Signing it in Visual Studio ([pictures](https://clickonceget.azurewebsites.net/Home/LearnMoreAboutCertificate#HowToSignByGitHubSSHKey)) and setting separate publish + install locations allows me to bypass the need to use mage at all!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the automated tools work well with all ins and outs of ClickOnce and its related tools, but doing things by hand is a real challenge.

Resources that were very useful to me are [Walkthrough: Manually Deploying a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx) and [Walkthrough: Manually Deploying a ClickOnce Application that Does Not Require Re-Signing and that Preserves Branding Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384246.aspx).

Options:

- Use automated tools available from Visual Studio to sign and deploy your application. (It has drawbacks too, but at least it works, sort of);
- Spend a lot of time automating and tweaking your process, as you currently do. In the end you will benefit from doing this because you have a lot more control over the end result;
- Use some other deployment method, like MSI.